# React Navigation: When is `getRehydratedState` triggered

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, router

I'm implementing a custom router by following [the official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-routers/).

The custom router needs to define the `getRehydratedState` method. I want to know what is the purpose of this method and when React Navigation invokes it.

Below is the only explanation on this method in the official documentation:

> Function which rehydrates the full navigation state from a given partial state. Receives a partial state object and an options object with routeNames and routeParamList properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is triggered whenever you pass a partial state to the navigator.

For example:

- You pass `initialState` to the `NavigationContainer`
- You pass a partial state in `navigation.reset`, `navigation.dispatch` etc.
- Partial state is received by parsing deep links

Or any other situation where state maybe partial and doesn't contain a `stale: false` property.